# Glide Not Loading Image

Tags: android, image, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-resources

I have saved my drawables in an integer array in a resource file but when i try reading it and loading it using the glide library i am unable to dispaly an image.

Adapter

```
public class CuisineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder_Cuisine> {

private Context context;
private TypedArray pictures;
private ArrayList<Integer> images;

public CuisineAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.images = new ArrayList<>();

    /*images.add(R.drawable.africa);
    images.add(R.drawable.bahamas);
    images.add(R.drawable.brazil);
    images.add(R.drawable.china);
    images.add(R.drawable.denmark);
    images.add(R.drawable.france);
    images.add(R.drawable.germany);
    images.add(R.drawable.great_britain);
    images.add(R.drawable.greece);
    images.add(R.drawable.india);
    images.add(R.drawable.ireland);
    images.add(R.drawable.israel);
    images.add(R.drawable.italy);
    images.add(R.drawable.japan);
    images.add(R.drawable.korea);
    images.add(R.drawable.mexico);
    images.add(R.drawable.russia);
    images.add(R.drawable.spain);
    images.add(R.drawable.thailand);
    images.add(R.drawable.united_arab_emirates);
    images.add(R.drawable.united_states_of_america);
    images.add(R.drawable.vietnam);*/

    pictures = context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.country_flags);
    Log.i("data", pictures.toString() + "");
}

@Override
public ViewHolder_Cuisine onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cuisine_type, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder_Cuisine(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder_Cuisine holder, int position) {

    int image = images.get(position);
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(image)
            .override(150, 150)
            .into(holder.getImageView());
    //holder.getImageView().setImageResource(image);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return images.size();
}
```

}

If i use holder.getImageView().setImageResource(image); instead of glide everything works well and i can display the image but this takes a lot of memory so i wanted to use glide.

```
<integer-array name="country_flags">
    <item>@drawable/africa</item>
    <item>@drawable/bahamas</item>
    <item>@drawable/brazil</item>
    <item>@drawable/china</item>
    <item>@drawable/denmark</item>
    <item>@drawable/france</item>
    <item>@drawable/germany</item>
    <item>@drawable/great_britain</item>
    <item>@drawable/greece</item>
    <item>@drawable/india</item>
    <item>@drawable/ireland</item>
    <item>@drawable/israel</item>
    <item>@drawable/italy</item>
    <item>@drawable/japan</item>
    <item>@drawable/korea</item>
    <item>@drawable/mexico</item>
    <item>@drawable/russia</item>
    <item>@drawable/spain</item>
    <item>@drawable/thailand</item>
    <item>@drawable/united_arab_emirates</item>
    <item>@drawable/united_states_of_america</item>
    <item>@drawable/vietnam</item>
</integer-array>
```

I tried using typed array but that for unsuccessful so i shifted to an arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem i realized is that glide loads only raster images and not vector images yet,so instead i used a vector image library to load vector images in my app.

[Sharp Vector Image Loading Library](https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp)